# CSOM without being an app for O365

Tags: office-365, office-integration

I have an integration dashboard I've written that currently works with On-Prem SharePoint.

Basically, you give it the address of a SharePoint server, and it passes in your NTLM credentials obtained through forms auth, and can access lists and libraries for you.

Can I do the same thing with O365? I can see how the App model works with CSOM, but this cannot be an App for a few reasons.

I assume there is an object model used by Windows Apps for SharePoint integration, but I can't seem to find it at the moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll .NET CSOM not only in SharePoint APPS, but also in other client solutions based on .NET. There are also more-specific .NET CSOM implementations for Silverlight and Windows Phone.